# Счётчик кликов по ссылке на JQuery  в CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, счетчики, php, codeigniter, javascript

Есть сайт, на котором статьи выводятся из базы данных в цикле. Что-то типа:

```
<?php foreach($article as $item):?>
 <div class="nazvanie_statii"><?=$item['title'];></div>
 <div class="kol_prosmotrov"><?=$item['view'];></div>
 <div class="text_statii"><?=$item['text'];></div>
 <a href="<?=base_url();?>index.php/article/<?=$item['title_en'];?>"/>
 <?php endforeach;>
```

Также имеется функция JQuery, которая подсчитывает количество кликов по блоку или ссылке с классом .myObj и выводит их в блоке с идентификатором-#counter.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myObj').click(function() {
        $('#counter').html(+$('#counter').html()+1);
    });
});
</script>
```

В общем, возник такой вопрос - как  её привязать к моей ссылочке - `<a href="<?=base_url();?>index.php/article/<?=$item['title_en'];?>"/>`?

Ведь она динамическая, каждый раз выводится по title_en-названию статьи в транскрипции.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, натолкните на мысль. Заранее спасибо.

Не у кого нет идей?
Вроде задумка должна не сложно реализовываться...
Или это вообще невозможно на лету...только через добавление количества кликов в бд и последующий вывод из бд в блоке `<div class="kol_prosmotrov"><?=$item['view'];></div>`

Понял, что пишу ерунду, ) ведь при перезагрузке страницы счётчик обнулится.
Тогда получается только через бд?

Comment: народ что за ограничение кол-ва вводимых символов для вопросов?)Вы серьёзно?дайте возможность показать код, я ведь пробую писать сам)

Answer (score 2):

1. Надо создать табличку в которой хранить число кликов, по вашим критериям
   и записывать результат.
2. Блокам или ссылкам присваивать `id`, например `id="counter_<?=$item['id']?>" name="<?=$item['id']?>"`, по котором вы будете их ловить.
3. В `javascript`:

   ```
   $('[id^=counter_]')click(function() {
       var id = this.name;
       $.post("/ajx/update_couter", {
           id:id
       }).done(function(data) {
           $(this).html(+$(this).html()+1);
       });
   });
   ```
4. `/ajx/update_couter` на стороне сервера принимать `id` вашей статьи и добавляет в базу `+1`.
5. А в `foreach` вы ее выводите или как-то другим способом.